# jquery fadeIn class workaround without UI

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, jquery-hover

I can't seem to take what I need from this code and make it work for myself, hoping someone can help.

I can not use the Jquery UI and makes hovers so much more difficult than they need to be. I have a sprite that I need to fade the hover in and out. .css() doesn't allow fade and it is a sprite that's being called by bg position

My plan is to add/remove a class on mouseenter/leave or hover. That part is easy, getting an easing effect is not. This is their code. How would I use something like this to just add and remove a class so I can fade it in to fake an animated/timed hover?

```
$(".nav").children("li").each(function() {
        var current = "nav current-" + ($(this).attr("class"));
        var parentClass = $(".nav").attr("class");
        if (parentClass != current) {
            $(this).children("a").css({backgroundImage:"none"});
        }
    }); 


    // create events for each nav item
    attachNavEvents(".nav", "home");
    attachNavEvents(".nav", "about");
    attachNavEvents(".nav", "services");
    attachNavEvents(".nav", "contact");


    function attachNavEvents(parent, myClass) {
        $(parent + " ." + myClass).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).append('<div class="nav-' + myClass + '"></div>');
            $("div.nav-" + myClass).css({display:"none"}).fadeIn(200);
        }).mouseout(function() {
            // fade out & destroy pseudo-link
            $("div.nav-" + myClass).fadeOut(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    }
```

The css I am using would simply be something like:

```
.btn_up {
width: 161px;
height: 40px;
background-position: -131px -310px;
margin:10px auto;
}

.btn_uphover{
background-position: -292px -310px !important;
-moz-opacity:0; 
filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
opacity:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't provide the exact code needed.
I think you are looking for the jQuery .animate function.
More info here:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You can do some seriously cool stuff with this function, Im sure you can get the effect your after using this. Try maybe animating the opacity.